# Merging multiple columns into one in pandas based on Boolean value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

How can I merge multiple columns into one column in pandas?

I have this table:

```
ID   | A   | B   | C | D
1      1     1     0   3
2      1     0     1   2
3      0     0     1   8
```

I want to get this table:

```
ID   | X | D
1      A   3
1      B   3
2      A   2
2      C   2
3      C   8
```

I want to merge column A,B,C into column X based on their values. If one id has multiple true (1) values merging columns (A/B/C) there will be a new row copy of that id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) to reshape the DataFrame, and then keep only the relevant columns and rows using [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) to select the rows and [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) to drop the now obsolete column, like this:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['ID', 'D'], var_name='X')
.query('value == 1')
.drop(columns=['value']))
#       ID  D  X
#0   1  3  A
#1   2  2  A
#3   1  3  B
#7   2  2  C
#8   3  8  C
```

The DataFrame after melt looks like this:

```
#   ID  D  X  value
#0   1  3  A      1
#1   2  2  A      1
#2   3  8  A      0
#3   1  3  B      1
#4   2  2  B      0
#5   3  8  B      0
#6   1  3  C      0
#7   2  2  C      1
#8   3  8  C      1
```

By using `ID` and `D` as `id_vars`, those are duplicated for every different value of all the other variables (`A`, `B` and `C`). The values of these columns are now in the `value` column. Then, it's a matter of keeping the rows where `value == 1`

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solutions:

```
df2 = df.set_index('ID')
df2[['A', 'B', 'C']].multiply(df2['D'], axis='index').reset_index()\
    .melt(id_vars='ID', var_name='X', value_name='D').query('D > 0')\
    .sort_values('ID')
```

The result is:

```
   ID  X  D
0   1  A  3
3   1  B  3
1   2  A  2
7   2  C  2
8   3  C  8
```

Compared to your desired result, there is additional (index) column,
but I think it's not important.